# What is exactly thermodynamic equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, definition, equilibrium

As I wrote in the question, what is [thermodynamic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium)? From what I understand is a state where the thermal, chemical properties don't change with respect of the time and there is a mechanical equilibrium as well. But can this be true for example, in a body with a temperature field with gradients? I was reviewing this concept because thermodynamic equilibrium is critical in defining a reversible process and I want to understand it well.

Comment: Please clarify your question to indicate what aspect isn't already addressed by the ample material at [thermodynamic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium).

Answer (score 1):

**Currents/flows of energy and matter**
One has to distinguish *equilibrium* and a *steady state*. In a steady state the characteristics of the system to not change with time, but there may be currents/flows present. E.g., a constant current flowing in a circuit is a steady state, but not an equilibrium one. Likewise, Sun is emitting radiation and losing energy, which is replenished via the thermonuclear reactions in its core - that is there is a constant flow of energy from the Sun core to its surface.

**Fast and slow relaxation processes**
One often discards the currents/flows by saying that all the fast relaxation processes have ended, whereas all the slow relaxation processes are too slow on the experimental scale. Thus, a mixture of hydrogen and oxygen might eventually turn into water, but triggering a burning reaction, this process is very slow, and the mixture can be treated as an equilibrium mixture of two gases.

**Local equilibrium**
Boltzmann distribution turns to zero the collision integral of the Boltzmann equation. One thus can describe a system in terms of a distribution function with parameters (temperature, pressure, etc.) slowly varying in space. This is referred to as the *local equilibrium*, and used to derive the equations of fluid dynamics from the Boltzmann equation.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers aren't wrong but I think I understand what you are looking for a bit better.

Thermodynamic equilibrium is a **dynamic** equilibrium that results from statistical mechanics. Let's say that we have an n-body system of an ideal gas (e.g., H2). We'll represent them as the red spheres below and say the starting temperature is 20C.

[image]

If we begin heating it up from an infinite external heat source that is 30C, you will begin with increased molecular speeds from the outer edge of the box, resulting in more collisions on the outside than the inside. Eventually, these collisions will propagate the heat throughout the box until the temperature is 30C inside the box.

> But can this be true for example, in a body with a temperature field with gradients?

At thermodynamic equilibrium, there are effectively no more temperature gradients. Remember, temperature is a statistical phenomenon, so it does not matter that there are some molecules moving faster than others. The point is, as we zoom out, we obtain the same *average molecular speeds and collision rates* everywhere in the box. That is thermodynamic equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

I think at least a part of your confusion comes down to the scale at which you are looking at the problems. Thermodynamic equilibrium will always somewhat depend on the context of your specific problem, but it will have some common features.

First of all, the it is the macroscopic observables of your system that will be relatively static at equilibrium, such as the pressure, the temperature, the number of each type of particle, and the volume (the ideal gas is the basic model for thermodynamic problems). Secondly, the macroscopic mechanical properties of your system will be basically fixed; i.e. nothing is moving on the macroscopic scale. This part is a little tricky, as thermal equilibrium does nothing to prevent microscopic fluctuations such as the motion of individual atoms or particles, which is intrinsically part of the kinetic definition of temperature. This is also why I gave the qualifiers like "basically fixed," as there will always be microscopic deviations even when we are in equilibrium. The problem with your example including thermal gradients is that it is impossible for two bodies with unequal temperatures to be in equilibrium. This is a consequence of the second law of thermodynamics, which can be shown to imply that heat will always transfer between bodies of unequal temperature until they reach the same temperature. Equilibrium is established by the second law when we are in a state of maximized global entropy (i.e. the entropy of the system and its surroundings, which would be the entire universe). A less complicated way of saying this is that we reach equilibrium when the entropy is no longer changing, which also means we are no longer changing temperature due to heat flow.

In the chemical context, equilibrium is also characterized by the lack of overall transformations between different states and identities of matter. In a simple case of a liquid-vapor equilibrium of a single substance, the number of particles in each phase will remain relatively constant in equilibrium. But do note that this is not the same as saying nothing is happening. It is simply that the rates of forward and reverse transformation between the two phases are equal. Thus, on the macroscopic scale, there is no net effect, and the system is equilibrated. In a chemical reaction, equilibrium is established when there is no net production of species on either side of the reaction arrow, though individual particles will still regularly transform back and forth.

I do not want to get further into the weeds without some clarification as to what specific aspect of thermodynamic equilibrium has you stuck, but hopefully this is some helpful food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for some reason I was confusing thermodynamic equilibrium with steady state of the properties of the system. From their definitions, I think I understand that a system in thermodynamic equilibrium is also in steady state but this also made me get confused because the each part of the system is also exchanging energy with their own parts.